# Is psychology a science or magic?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

What makes a person to be ever smiling to an extent that they just can't be angry or actually show they are angry even if they are?

Comment: Realization that there is no need in anger or, if it nevertheless manages to get risen automatically by one of the relevant reflexes or instincts, there's no need in using it. It is evaluated by the person as merely a signal or indication. Anger is but a reaction created by nature and is meaningful for our survival in certain situations. A person mature and wise enough will surely abandon anger in favor of constructivism. This is true for other non-positive feelings too, for example, sadness.

Answer (score 1):

From David Myer's Psychology, 10th edition, Page 6,

> Psychology is the **science** of behavior and mental processes.

To answer your actual question, here is what David has said in general that there are 3 levels on which Psychology can be viewed at differently. Following image lists them.
[image]

Each level forms an independent yet dependent abstraction with other two. So, to answer your question, the person's current external environment(Socio-Cultural environment which could include his friends, family, lover, stranger, native or foreign society, etc.), internal environment (current biological state which includes hormones,health, other physiological processes, maybe some disease) and Psychological influences(Learned behavior and knowledge shapes the understanding and interpretation of context ) might have created a triad to give the resultant situation.

So, the person might have scored a perfect score in SATs but might have had a emotional breakup the same time which might lead to the situation mentioned by you. Of course, there are infinite possibilities.
I just listed one of the possible Socio-cultural factor. Use your imagination to figure out the rest of the infinite possibilities.

Good Luck.

**P.S:** It is not magic BTW!
From Wikipedia,

> Magic or sorcery is the use of rituals, symbols, actions, gestures and
>   language that are believed to exploit supernatural forces.